Can bulkOperationRunQuery return all products from a store?
I would like to use a bulk operation to return all product ids and some more info. In the documentation, there is no hard limit specified. There are some posts that specify that sometimes the queries can return a fraction of the data.
Is there any way to enforce the query to return all products?
Otherwise, how can you combine a bulkOperationRunQuery with cursor/pagination such that I would manage to get all products?
